# Consider the Function $f(x,y)=2\cos(x)\cos(y)$ for $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and $0\leq y\leq \pi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The Question is to find the location of the saddle points of f, find the value of f at the saddle points, find the location of the minima and maxima points of f and the value of f at the minima and maxima points.

I have used the hessian criterion to work out the critical points $(π(n-1/2), π/2 +2πn)$, $(π(n-1/2), 3π/2 + 2πn)$, $(πn, 2πn)$ and $(πn, π + 2πn)$.

To classify this, I know I must require $$D(x,y)=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$$
I have done this to get $$D(x,y)=4\cos^2(y)\cos^2(x)-4\sin^2x\sin^2y$$

Now this is where i am confused. The question stated that for $0≤x≤π$ and $0≤y≤π$ which means that i don't have to consider it if x, y are between 0 and π right? my critical points are full of n's and stuff which is making the last step of the question difficult for me to understand as i know i need to evaluate D at these critical points but i do not know how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused. What's the point of expressing the critical points in terms of an integer $n$ if the problem provides $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $\pi$ (both included)? And you acknowledge that, yet you then say you don't have to consider it if $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Factoring, you get: $$D(x,y)=4\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)$$ at least if your formula for $D$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you, i should have worded that much better i apologise. i eventually figured it out. but thank you none the less!!